# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalidのバリデーションエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

グループの投稿機能を作っていたのですが、投稿ボタンを押したら、バリデーションに失敗しました。circleを入力してください。と表示されるので、rails cを打ち、Circlepost.firstと入力すると

```
<Circlepost id: 11, content: "k", user_id: 1, created_at: "2021-04-27 03:31:41", updated_at: "2021-04-27 03:31:41", circle_id: nil>
```

このようにcircle_idが入っていませんでした。

---

circle(グループ)
user
circlepost(グループ投稿)

---

これはルートに問題があるのかコントローラーに問題があるのかわかりません。ルートやコントローラーをいじってみても分からなかったので、どういったように変更すれば良いか教えていただきたいです。

ちなみにグループの投稿はpostlistというページに表示するようにしています。

#### routes.rb

```
 resources :circles do
    member do
      get :postlist
    end
  end

postlist_circle GET    /circles/:id/postlist(.:format)                                                          circles#postlist
```

#### /app/controllers/circleposts_controller.rb

```
 class CirclepostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_circle,   only: :destroy
require 'pry'

  def create
    @circle = Circle.find_by(id: params[:circle_id])
    @circlepost = current_user.circleposts.build(circlepost_params)
    @circlepost.circle_id = params[:circle_id]
    @circlepost.image.attach(params[:circlepost][:image])
    if @circlepost.save!
      flash[:success] = "投稿しました。"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    @circlepost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "投稿を削除しました。"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private
  
    def circlepost_params
      params.require(:circlepost).permit(:content, :image)
    end
    
    def correct_circle
      @circlepost = current_user.circleposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @circlepost.nil?
    end
end
```

#### モデル

```
belongs_to :circle, optional: true
belongs_to :user

ユーザーとグループに関連づけています。※ユーザーとグループ側にも関連付けしています。
```

#### /app/views/circles/postlist.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'postlist') %>

  <h3 class="circle-name"><%= @circle.name %></h3>
  <div class="postlist">
    <% if @circle.circle_user?(current_user) %>
      <section class="circlepost_form">
        <%= render 'shared/circlepost_form' %>
      </section>
    <% end %>
          
    <% if @circle.circleposts.any? %>
      <ol class="circleposts">
        <%= render @circleposts %>
      </ol>
      <div class="page">
         <%= will_paginate @circleposts, { :previous_label => '&lt 前へ', :next_label => '次へ &gt' } %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

#### /app/views/shared/_circlepost_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @circlepost, local: true) do |b| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages_second', object: b.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= b.text_area :content, placeholder: "(例)　活動時間を変更したので確認してください！" %>
  </div>
  <%= b.submit "投稿", class: "btn btn-warning" %>
  <span class="image">
    <%= b.file_field :image, accept: "image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

#### ログ

```
Started POST "/circleposts" for 126.227.240.207 at 2021-04-27 14:19:34 +0000
Cannot render console from 126.227.240.207! Allowed networks: 126.227.199.43, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
   (1.8ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by CirclepostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"pgdArkzFtgJKP1AYL0hjpJTnRBpCaQL47awdeH/E1svA88nIqY/RrdXLROzMzH7BW6L9YRcL4aA8rGPx26PkLg==", "circlepost"=>{"content"=>"d"}, "commit"=>"投稿"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:18:in `current_user'
  Circle Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "circles".* FROM "circles" WHERE "circles"."id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/circleposts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 424ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms | Allocations: 207665)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (バリデーションに失敗しました: Circleを入力してくださ
```

Comment: `@circlepost.circle_id = params[:circle_id]`が怪しいですね。実際に投稿してみたときのログを追記していただけますか？

Comment: こんにちは。ログを追加してみました。

Comment: やはり、`params[:circle_id]`が存在していませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`circle_id`をコントローラに渡す必要があります。方法は2つあります。
まず、`app/views/shared/_circlepost_form.html.erb`のフォームの項目から`circle_id`を選択できるようにすることです。この方法のメリットはフォーム以外を修正する必要がないことですが、デメリットとしてはフォームに項目が増えてしまってユーザビリティを損ねる可能性が挙げられます。
もう一つの方法は、`config/routes.rb`を修正して以下のようにすることです。

```rb
resources :circles do
    member do
      get :postlist
      resources :circleposts
    end
end
```

こうすることで、Circlepostsの作成先URLが`/circleposts`から`circles/:circle_id/circleposts`に変わり、URLからサークルのIDを取得できるようになります。
この方法のメリットはユーザー体験を変更しないことです。デメリットは既存のフォームのURLも変更になってしまう点です。

メリットとデメリット、更には実装の難易度などを考慮して決定するとよいかと思います。

Comment: あなたは救世主です。ルートを変更する方法で解決しました。解決方法から様々なことを想定して実装していくのですね。勉強になります。初学者にもわかりやすく教えていただきありがとうございました。